# conditional merging with datetime index

Tags: python

df1 looks like this-

```
week_date                   Values
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10
28-04-2019 00:00:00          20
```

df2 looks like this-

```
hourly_date                 hour_val
21-04-2019 00:00:00            a
21-04-2019 01:00:00            b
21-04-2019 02:00:00            c
21-04-2019 03:00:00            d
28-04-2019 00:00:00            e
```

resultant dataset should look like this

```
week_date                 Values      hourly_date                 hour_val
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 00:00:00            a
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 01:00:00            b
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 02:00:00            c
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 03:00:00            d
28-04-2019 00:00:00          20        28-04-2019 00:00:00            e
```

I have hundreds of weekly rows data and thousands of hourly rows data.
trying merging but not getting the desired output.

```
merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

resultant dataset should look like this

```
week_date                 Values      hourly_date                 hour_val
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 00:00:00            a
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 01:00:00            b
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 02:00:00            c
21-04-2019 00:00:00          10        21-04-2019 03:00:00            d
28-04-2019 00:00:00          20        28-04-2019 00:00:00            e
```

Comment: not getting the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can merge on `year` and `week` in this case, try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "week_date": ["21-04-2019 00:00:00", "28-04-2019 00:00:00"],
    "Values": [10,20]
}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "hourly_date": [
        "21-04-2019 00:00:00",
        "21-04-2019 01:00:00",
        "21-04-2019 02:00:00",
        "21-04-2019 03:00:00",
        "28-04-2019 00:00:00"
    ],
    "hour_val": ["a","b","c","d","e"]
}
)

df1.week_date = pd.to_datetime(df1.week_date)
df1 = df1.set_index("week_date", drop=False)

df2.hourly_date = pd.to_datetime(df2.hourly_date)
df2 = df2.set_index("hourly_date", drop=False)

pd.merge(df1, df2, 
         left_on=[df1.week_date.dt.week, df1.week_date.dt.year],
         right_on=[df2.hourly_date.dt.week, df2.hourly_date.dt.year]
        )[["week_date", "Values","hourly_date","hour_val"]].set_index("week_date")
```

this outputs

```
         Values hourly_date hour_val
week_date           
2019-04-21  10  2019-04-21 00:00:00 a
2019-04-21  10  2019-04-21 01:00:00 b
2019-04-21  10  2019-04-21 02:00:00 c
2019-04-21  10  2019-04-21 03:00:00 d
2019-04-28  20  2019-04-28 00:00:00 e
```

Comment: please check the above comments

Answer (score -1):

not getting the desired result

my original data sets look this this

data-1:
week_date               value
2019-04-19 20:00:00      10
2019-04-26 20:00:00      20

data-2:
hourly_date              hour_val
2019-04-26 01:00:00       a 
2019-04-26 02:00:00       b
2019-04-26 03:00:00       c
2019-04-26 20:00:00       d
2019-04-26 21:00:00       e

and the desired output should be-

```
                 Values    hourly_date       hour_val
```

week_date
2019-04-19 20:00:00  10     2019-04-26 01:00:00   a
2019-04-19 20:00:00  10     2019-04-26 02:00:00   b
2019-04-19 20:00:00  10     2019-04-26 03:00:00   c
2019-04-26 20:00:00  20     2019-04-26 20:00:00   d
2019-04-26 20:00:00  20     2019-04-26 21:00:00   e

means weekly date-time changes only when it's equal to hourly date-time...else week_date carries the previous date-time value